# SolrCloud 4.8.0 - Snapshot directories take a lot of space

Tags: solr

Looking at solrhome/data directory in my solrcloud cluster I have found a lot of old snapshot directories like these:

```
snapshot.20150506003702765
snapshot.20150506003702760
snapshot.20150507002849492
snapshot.20150507002849473
snapshot.20150507002849459
```

or even a month older. These directories keep really a lot of space, 2 or 3 times the whole index.

May I delete these directories? If yes, is there a best practice, should I restart solrcloud?

Answer (score 1):

Those directories are created with the Solr replication handler and are safe to delete; they're not currently in use so no restart is required. Full documentation is available [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication).